# Conservative Approximation of Kleene-Mycroft Iteration for Polymorphic Recursion?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, type-theory, type-inference, recursion, polymorphism

To perform type inference in the presence of polymorphic recursion, one can use a *Kleene-Mycroft* iteration to compute the principal type of an expression. To type $\mathsf{fix}\ f\ldotp e$, we define $F(\sigma)$ as the principal type of $e$ under the assumption that $f : \sigma$. We can then define $\sigma_0 = \forall a \ldotp a$ and $\sigma_{i+1} = F(\sigma_i)$, until we reach a fixed-point $\sigma_k$. This $\sigma_k$ is then the principal type of $\mathsf{fix}\ f\ldotp e$.

There are two key issues with this:

- Inference with polymorphic recursion is undecidable, so this iteration may not always reach a fixed-point.
- The approximation at each stage of the iteration is not sound: if we quit after $j<k$ iterations, not only will $\sigma_j$ not be the principal type of $\mathsf{fix}\ f\ldotp e$, but it will not be a type of $\mathsf{fix}\ f\ldotp e$ at all, since we made too strong of an assumption about the type of $f$ when checking $e$.

I'm wondering if there's a standard way to soundly approximate polymorphic recursion: that is, to iterate some number of times, and afterwards, obtain a type that is possibly less general than the principal type, but that is nevertheless a valid typing of $\mathsf{fix}\ f\ldotp e$.

For example, one can imagine the Hindley-Milner approximation, where we type $e$ under the assumption that $f$ has a monomorphic type, as being the 0-ary approximation. We may fail to find a typing for an expression that requires polymorphic recursion, but if we find a type, we know that it is a valid typing of the expression.

Does such an approximation exist?

Answer (score 7):

You should have a look at the following paper -- and the previous work by Gori and Levi:

[On Polymorphic Recursion, Type Systems, and Abstract Interpretation](https://users.dimi.uniud.it/~marco.comini/Papers/PolRecTySysAbsInt/PolRecTySysAbsInt08.pdf)
Marco Comini, Ferruccio Damiani, Samuel Vrech, 2008

> The problem of typing polymorphic recursion (i.e., recursive function
>   definitions rec {x = e} where different occurrences of x in e are used
>   with different types) has been investigated both by people working on
>   type systems and by people working on abstract interpretation.
>   Recently, Gori and Levi have developed an abstract interpreter that is
>   able to type all the ML typable recursive definitions and interesting
>   examples of polymorphic recursion. The problem of finding a type
>   system corresponding to their abstract interpreter was open.
>
> In this paper we present a type system corresponding to the Gori-Levi
>   abstract interpreter. Interestingly enough, the type system is derived
>   from the system of simple types (which is the let-free fragment of the
>   ML type system) by adapting a general technique for extending
>   a decidable type system enjoying principal typings by adding
>   a decidable rule for typing recursive definitions. The key role played
>   in our investigation by the notion of principal typing suggests that
>   this notion might be useful in other investigations about the
>   relations between type systems and type inference algorithms
>   synthesized by abstract interpretation.